# cannot parse json string into nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

Im trying to parse a json string using sbjsonparser. Im having trouble converting it to nsdictionary. I've used sbjsonparser in my other classes and they all worked fine. see my code.

```
-(void)parseJsonString
{
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init]; 
    NSDictionary *dict;
    dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);


    NSDictionary *dict2;
    dict2 = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict2);

   [parser release];
```

}

here's my console output:

```
2011-08-12 13:56:55.098 EasyQuiz[5446:13603] [{
"q": "Question Testing", 
"score": 1, 
"c3": "Choice C", 
"c2": "Choice B", 
"c1": "Choice A", 
"rev": 1, 
"id": 1, 
"c4": "Choice D"
}]
2011-08-12 13:56:55.686 EasyQuiz[5446:13603] (null)
2011-08-12 13:56:56.296 EasyQuiz[5446:13603] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start  
of token []
2011-08-12 13:56:56.297 EasyQuiz[5446:13603] (null)
```

I checked the string at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it appears to be valid. what do you think is causing this problem? thanks!

I printed the error in dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil]; and it says:

```
  Error Domain=org.brautaset.SBJsonParser.ErrorDomain Code=0 "Illegal start of token []" 
  UserInfo=0x62eb920 {NSLocalizedDescription=Illegal start of token []}
```

**EDIT**
I tried hardcoding the jsonstring like this

```
NSString *thisJsonString = @"[{\"q\": \"Question Testing\",\"score\": 1, \"c3\": \"Choice C\", \"c2\": \"Choice B\", \"c1\": \"Choice A\", \"rev\": 1, \"id\": 1, \"c4\": \"Choice D\"}]";

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dict;

dict = [parser objectWithString:thisJsonString error:nil];
NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);

[parser release];
```

and I got what I want in the console:

```
dict (
    {
    c1 = "Choice A";
    c2 = "Choice B";
    c3 = "Choice C";
    c4 = "Choice D";
    id = 1;
    q = "Question Testing";
    rev = 1;
    score = 1;
}
)
```

**EDIT**
In case you want to know where I get the data. I downloading a zip file from a website using asihttprequest and the this file is extracted using objective-zip and the extracted file is read like this.

```
NSString *filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]  
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json.zip"];

    //Opening zip file for reading...
    progressLabel.text = @"Reading file...";
    ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:filePath mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];

    //Opening first file...
    progressLabel.text = @"Opening file...";
    [unzipFile goToFirstFileInZip];
    ZipReadStream *read1= [unzipFile readCurrentFileInZip];

    //Reading from first file's stream...
    NSMutableData *data1= [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:1000000] autorelease];//100MB
    int bytesRead1= [read1 readDataWithBuffer:data1];
    NSLog(@"bytes: %d",bytesRead1);
    if (bytesRead1 > 0) {
        progressLabel.text = @"File is good!";
        jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
//.... more codes follow, but this is how I get jsonString
```

Comment: I am not sure what is going wrong but that is not a dictionary its an array

Comment: Im not sure I understand you right, but Im using this code to convert that json string into an nsdictionary using this code. This piece of code works fine in all my other classes. just this feed is giving me errors.

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init]; 
    NSDictionary *dict;
    dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);

Comment: If the string is an array you can't force it to be converted to a dictionary.  Look at the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) -- "object" in JSON is an NSDictionary but "array" is NSArray/

Answer (score 0):

Your json is an array of one object, so you can't directly parse it to NSDictionary. First parse it to NSArray and then take first object and put it into a NSDictionary

```
-(void)parseJsonString
{

   NSArray *jsonArray = (*NSArray)[jsonString JSONValue];

   NSDictionary *jsonDict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *q = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"q"];
   ...

}
```

Comment: I get this error: -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token []
and when nslog the string, I get this. (null)

Comment: I get the same error.  NSString does not receive a -JSONValue message.

Comment: Figured it out.  If you are getting the -JSONValue failed message, you are not using the NSString+SBJSON.h category.  The original question author does specify that he is using the SBJSON project.

Answer (score -1):

objectWithString:error: is having return type **id**, modify your code as below and let me know.

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil]]; 
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"response", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict description]);
```

Comment: I get this exception:
Exception caught: NSException - [<__NSDictionary0 0x69d8750> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key response.

Comment: I get this:
{
    response = "(null)";
}
:-(

Comment: I have checked it the URL that I have and it's showing me one object contained by the NSDictionary and that's why I have edited the code. Let me check it with your JSON string. I'll let you know.

Comment: It's responding me following value, **"(\n        {\n        c1 = \"Choice A\";\n        c2 = \"Choice B\";\n        c3 = \"Choice C\";\n        c4 = \"Choice D\";\n        id = 1;\n        q = \"Question Testing\";\n        rev = 1;\n        score = 1;\n    }\n)";**

Comment: the \n is causing the problem?

Comment: No, not at all. It's working perfectly at my end. Even it is showing me the value for response key. \n is not a problem. It's strange!!!

Comment: I found the problem already. It's in my NSMutableData *data1= [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:1000000] autorelease] (see my edited code above). I counted the number of characters in my jsonstring and it's exactly 129. I tried changing initWithLength to 129 and it works, but beyond or less than 129 it will not work. The question now is about the objective-zip :D. how am i going to know the bytes for the file that is being read so I can set the initWithLength with the exact length?

Comment: solved it. just did some memory management when extracting the file. thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out what the above code is trying to accomplish.